# Sort Only Part of a String in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Okay so I have database and I need to extract only certain rows that have 111 in them.

so basically by db looks like this:

> ```
> ------------ ------------
> |     ID     |     AB     |
>  ------------ ------------
> |     1      |   bc112    |
>  ------------ ------------
> |     2      |   cd111    |
>  ------------ ------------
> |     3      |   ac111    |
>  ------------ ------------
> |     4      |   bd121    |
>  ------------ ------------
> ```

I thought that this line would work:

```
SELECT AB
FROM THING
WHERE AB='* 111';
```

but that didn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `%` instead of `*` and `like` instead of `=` :

```
SELECT AB
FROM THING
WHERE AB like '%111';
```

Comment: WOW, I can't believe I forgot about the "LIKE" condition! Thank you!